QGIS displaying images on Map tips using relative paths not working
I’m trying to view about 120 photos in  QGIS map tips. photos are in a sub folder called “photos” in the project folder “photos_arg”.
First I imported the photos using import geotagged photos and viewed them in map tips using
img src=file:///[%photo%]>

where “photo” is the field containing absolute path in the attribute table.
Since I want to share this work, I want to use the relative paths for the photos. So I created a field “path” and updated it with @project_folder||’/photos/’|| filename  using field calculator. I then replaced all the backslashes with forward slashes.
And used the same expression with <img src=file:///[% path%]> but it won't work.
But when I remove the <img tag it correctly points to the path field and display the path.
I suppose it recognizes the path correctly.
Also when I used drag and drop designer todisplay  the photos in attribute table using “path’ field , it works correctly.

I tried with adding only the folder name/file name ('with the project folder set in project properties and all paths saving in relative) but still didn't work.
read
: Creating map tip with pictures stored in relative path , Map tips and use of reltive paths
but still unable to find a solution.
Also, I tried importing pictures with both the Gpkg and shp files. still no luck.
Am I doing something wrong here or is there another way to import geotagged photos?

Is the file extension of the image missing ?

I  finally managed to get this to work. My dynamic path field in the attribute table did not update when I moved the project folder. So I made the html expression to get the dynamic path. I'll post what I did below.
I put the images in a subfolder of the project folder.
Set the project_home to the project folder (project-properties).
Import the photos using import geotagged photos, save as gpkg.
Add a new text field to the attribute table(say "path"). Populate it using
'photo folder/'||filename||'.jpg'

if there are backslashes in the field, replace them with forward slashes.
Then updated the html map tip expression to include the path dynamically.
<img src="file:///[% @project_home || '/' || "path" %]" width="300" >

And it worked!
But you have to set the project home when you open the project in another location. Trying to find a fix for that.
